# giving value from one class to extended one Java

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I dont really know how to explain myself on this so ill just show you guys what im supposed to do and what i got.
My teacher told us to complete the rest of the code so that the main will work.
This is what was given to me:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
dog buli=new dog();
cat felix=new cat(); 
cuckoo wallwatch=new cuckoo();
talks(buli);
talks(felix);
talks(wallwatch); }
}
```

the output should be:
guau 
miau
cucu

And what ive got(this class animals is where the main is too):

```
public abstract class Animals {
public String sound;
Animals (String sound){
    this.sonido = sound;
}
    public void talks(){
    System.out.println(sound);
}
```

And just the dog underclass(dog.java) since the three are the same:

```
public class dog extends Animals{

dog (String sound){
    sound = "guau";
}
```

}

To tell you the truth i have a lot of problems with java I've never had with other languages, 
i cant seem to understand anything related to classes or objects. :S
Thank you.

Comment: `Dog dog = new Dog("rover");`   Then to call it:  `dog.talk();`

Comment: the main can not be editted

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Animals {
   private String sound;
   public Animal(String sound){
      this.sound = sound;
   }

  public void talks(){
     System.out.println(sound);
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   public Dog() {
      super("woof");
  }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
   public Cat() {
      super("meow");
   }
}


public class Main {
     public static void talks(Animal animal) {
        animal.talk();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog= new Dog();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        talks(dog);
        talks(cat);
   }
}
```

Comment: i cant modify the main

Comment: create cat and cuckoo class similar to Dog. Then you can replicate the main.

Comment: im telling you i cant create any objects like dog dog = new dog("woof") if i could i wouldnt be asking here, though thx for answering

Comment: The subclasses Dog and Cat have zero-param constructors, but they call their parent class constructor passing in a sound specific to their type (e.g. Dog, Cat).

Comment: man, i cant edit the main, thats ( i guess) the point of the program, or maybe my teacher wrote it wrongly (which i doubt cause he loves making us suffer)

Comment: If by any chance you see this, can you explain to me what does this mean: public static void talks(Animal animal) {
        animal.talk();
     }

Comment: `public static void talks(Animal animal) { animal.talk(); }` is a `public` `static` method that takes an Animal as it parameter and invokes the method `talks()` on the animal. 'static' means the method is defined on the class instead of instances of the class (objects).

Comment: thx man, our teacher is pretty awful even though he knows a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the same class which contains main function, add the following function.

```
private static void talks(Animals animal) {
    animal.talk();
}
```

Then write following classes. (Note each class should be in a different file with name "class-name.java".... **dog.java**, **Animals.java** etc.)

Animals.java

```
public class Animals {
    public String sound;

    Animals(String sound) {
        this.sonido = sound;
    }

    public void talks() {
        System.out.println(sound);
    }
}
```

dog.java

```
public class dog extends Animals{

    dog (String sound){
        super(sound);
    }
}
```

Similarly the rest..

Good luck